# Create Mail Sender Object

Tags: c#, outlook

I am creating an Email Object in Outlook 2013, but I cannot find how to create the Sender object. I am using this code:

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)
         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mail.To = "mail@gmail.com"
mail.Sender = // What goes here?
mail.Subject = "Mail subject";
```

The Sender object is an implementation of the `Outlook.AddressEntry` interface, so there must be an implementation somewhere, but where? Is it possible to create this Sender object?

BTW, the sender of the email is not necessary an account registered in Outlook, so I cannot use the `mail.SendUsingAccount` property for that.

Comment: are you trying to send email through outlook? or through an exchange server? there is a difference.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: No, I am not trying to send the email thru Outlook. I am just trying to save an Email Object in a folder.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to *Dmitry Streblechenko* on his comments above I could get the answer, and these are the lines to create an `AddressEntry` and assign it to a `Sender`:

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Outlook.Recipient recipient = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CreateRecipient("mymail@domain.com");
mail.Sender = recipient.AddressEntry;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set this property `Outlook.MailItem.Sender` directly.

Only in cases where there are multiple account configured in the Outlook client, you can set this property to the `AddressEntry` object of the user that is represented by the `CurrentUser` property of a specific account.

More Info: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056.aspx

Comment: OK, but the property is not Read-Only either, that means it allows values to be set.

Comment: I was thinking about that too. I think it's read-write only to accomodate the multiple account scenario. In other words, I bet there's a check in the `Setter` that validates that the `AddressEntry` is in the list of authorised accounts on the Client. Have you tried creating an `AddressEntry` with a fake email address and setting the `Sender`?

Comment: `AddressEntry` is an Interface, one cannot create an `AddressEntry`. It does not necessary needs to be that property (_Sender_), it can be any other property that makes the email to show the **From** value of the email.

Comment: An Interface is an Object too. The fact the documentation says it is an Object does not necessary means it contains implementation. And yes, it is an Interface, you can see it from VS.

Comment: AddressEntry object is the .Net wrapper around the AddressEntry interface that comes from OOM.  And instance of AddressEntry object can be retrieved from other OOM object (Namespace.AddressLists, Namespace.CreateRecipient/Recipient.Resolve/Recipient.AddressEntry, etc.)