# How can I change the Sender Email Address in C#?

Tags: c#, html, outlook

```
    public static void emailSenden(object mail, string example)
    {

        MailItem answeremail = (mail as MailItem).Reply();
```

This is what I tried to do, however it doesn't work.

```
        (mail as MailItem).SenderEmailAddress ???
```

How does the code look **like to change the Sender Email adress?**

*//The **Sender Email adress in this reply should be my Email adress**";*

In this part is the Body part of the replymail:

```
        answeremail.HTMLBody = "<p> Completion not possible. Can you complete </p>" + example +
            "<br>" +
            "<p> manually</p>" +
            "<br>" +
            "<p>See you</p>" +
            "<br>" +
            "<p>Sala</p>";

        answermail.Send();

    }
```

Comment: Please add some info on which office version you are using. Sender cannot be set directly as it is read only. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506373/create-mail-sender-object

Comment: Try setting `answeremail.Sender.Address = "abc@def.com"`

Comment: I am doing it with answermail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "string";

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MailItem.Sender,it returns the addressee