# How to put the email's sender using C#, I have 3 email in my outlook application

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that will automatically send an email from outlook using C#.I have 3 emails in my outlook application, Is it possible to choose between 3 emails to be the sender of the email?
Don't know how. Please help!

This is my code when I click the send button it will automatically send an email.

```
try
{
    Outlook._Application _mpp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_mpp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mail.To = txtTo.Text;
    mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = txtMessage.Text;
    mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
    ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
    MessageBox.Show("Your message has been successfuly sent", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [`MailItem.Sender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Mail Sender Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506373/create-mail-sender-object)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SendUsingAccount` to send the mail with one of your Outlook accounts:

```
try
{
    Outlook._Application _mpp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_mpp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mail.To = txtTo.Text;
    mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = txtMessage.Text;
    mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;

/*************/
Outlook.Accounts accounts = _mpp.Session.Accounts;

string senderAddress = "wanted-sender-mail-address@xy.com";
foreach(Outlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    if(senderAddress.Equals(account.SmtpAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        mail.SendUsingAccount = account;
        break;
    }
}
/*************/

    ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
    MessageBox.Show("Your message has been successfuly sent", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```